# Unable to find NDK in SDK tools in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I have an Android Studio of version 3.4.2 in which

> Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools

traversing to this does not show NDK option to download, Android studio only shows NDK (Side by side), Http proxy is selected to no proxy, no vpn is connected for internet.
[image]

Is there a way to get NDK option and download from the SDK tools?
Are there any options in the IDE to enable and download?
Any type of help will be considered. thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question. Your picture clearly shows that the NDK is already installed on your machine. How come you did not find it?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Android NDK which is showing in the picture is this same as NDK? as I have updated to newer android studio. is the NDK tag named as Android Studio now?

Comment: Yes, I think the NDK and Android NDK are the same things!

Comment: Okay!. This is confusing for those updated to newer version of android studio. as older versions had tag as >**NDK** and now as >**Android NDK**. google should at least make this as >**NDK (Android NDK)** for better denotation. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The name *NDK* is replaced with *Android NDK* in recently version of Android Studio.
The picture above show The android ndk r20 already installed.
The alternative way to use the NDK is downloaded stand alone version at [Developer NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) and you can choose what version you wants.
Which stand alone version, you need to config the path of NDK inside *local.properties* in your project.

Comment: I needed to *remove* the NDK reference in the local.properties as it overrode definitions in the build.gradle.  But thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Hi @SMBiggs, yeah, your comment is right, as new version of AGP has changed again.
I don't remember exactly the when new version Gradle  has changed, they removed the ndk.dir in local.properties and use ndkVersion at build.gradle instead.